# Calculate year from date difference in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to calculate the number of years between two dates.

eg :- `Select to_date('30-OCT-2013') - TO_date('30-SEP-2014') FROM DUAL;`

This would result to 335 days. I want to show this in years, which will be `.97` years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply do this(divide by **365.242199**):

```
Select (to_date('30-SEPT-2014') - TO_date('30-OCT-2013'))/365.242199 FROM DUAL;
```

**1 YEAR = 365.242199 days**

OR

Try something like this using [MONTHS_BETWEEN](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions089.htm):-

```
select floor(months_between(date '2014-10-10', date '2013-10-10') /12) from dual;
```

or you may also try this:-

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date1) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date2) FROM DUAL;
```

## On a side note:-

> ***335/365.242199 = 0.917199603 and not .97***

Comment: Select (to_date('30-OCT-2013') - TO_date('30-SEP-2014'))/12 FROM DUAL;  IS not working... its giving -25.333333333333 as the answer

Comment: @sonakshisinha:- Also change the position of the dates to get rid of the minus sign.!! :)

Comment: i wanted to avoid dividing the date by 365 days ... as in leap year thr are 366 years and otherwise 365

Comment: ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0 : Select (to_date('30-SEPT-2014') - TO_date('30-OCT-2013'))/365.242199 FROM DUAL

Comment: @sonakshisinha:- the most proable cause for the error is  You tried to enter a date value using a specified date format, but you entered a non-numeric character where a numeric character was expected.

Comment: @sonakshisinha:- **Solution:** Check the date formats recognized by the to_date function. Correct the date value and retry.

Comment: @sonakshisinha:- Also check the datatype of the column in which you are storing the dates!! Hope that will help :)

Comment: +1 for MONTHS_BETWEEN which IMO is the best solution.

Comment: -1 (rather unkindly I admit) because although 3 solutions are offered, they are NOT the same and the subtle differences between them are not explained.

Comment: Just a heads up: I used your value for 1 year (365.242199 days) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47505251/5576771

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you figure that's .97 years.  Here's what I get:

```
SQL> SELECT  ( TO_date('30-SEP-2014') - to_date('30-OCT-2013')) /
                (ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2013-10-30',12) - DATE '2013-10-30') "Year Fraction" 
       FROM DUAL;

Year Fraction
-------------
0.91780821917
```

You're going to have to pick a date to base your year calculation on. This is one way to do it. I chose to make a year be the number of days between 10/30/2013 and 10/30/2014.  You could also make it a year between 9/30/2013 and 9/30/2014.

As an aside, if you're only interested in 2 decimal places, 365 is pretty much as good as 366.

UPDATE: Used ADD_MONTHS in calculating the denominator. That way you can use the same date for the entire calculation of the number of days in a year.

Comment: OP has mentioned in my comments that she wants to avoid dividing the date by 365 days :(

Comment: see basically i want to use this as one of my conditions.. i want to calculate <=1    between two dates...

Comment: @Rahul, I'd rather be right 3/4 of the time, than wrong all the time :-)

Comment: @DCookie:- I didnt said that you are wrong. I just tried to provide the details of OP's requirement which were there in my comments. Both of us are on the same page. ;)

Comment: @DCookie:- Not an issue Sir. It is obvious as OP has mentioned that in comments! ;)

Comment: @Rahul, no offence taken at all. I think it's kind of funny.

Comment: @DCookie:- Yes sure Sir. I already said we both are on the same page!! :)

Comment: @DCookie:- In between I like your edit and the change from 365 to (DATE '2014-10-30' - DATE '2013-10-30'). So atleast +1 from my side. As there is not enough upvoting for our answers ;)

Comment: Hi dcookie.. thnx  pretty much like the solutioning.

Answer (score 0):

None of the methods proposed in the other answers give exactly the same answer, look:

```
with dates as ( select to_date('2013-10-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as date1, to_date('2014-09-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') as date2 from dual)

select months_between(date2, date1)/12 as years_between, 'months_between(date1, date2)' as method from dates
union
select (date2 - date1)/365.242199, '(date2 - date1) / 365.242199' from dates
union
select extract(year from date2) - extract(year from date1), 'extract(year) from date2 - extract(year from date1)' from dates
union
select (date2 - date1) / (ADD_MONTHS(date1 ,12) - date1), '(nb days between date1 and date2) / (nb days in 1 year starting at date1)' from dates
;
```

gives

```
YEARS_BETWEEN                               METHOD

0.9166666666666666666666666666666666666667  months_between(date1, date2)
0.9171996032145234127231831719422979380321  (date2 - date1) / 365.242199
0.9178082191780821917808219178082191780822  nb days date2-date1 / (nb days in 1 year starting at date1)
1                                           extract(year) from date2 - extract(year from date1)
```

Why? Because they are all answering slightly different questions.

- MONTHS_BETWEEN gives the number of whole months between the 2 dates, and calculates the fractional part as the remainder in days divided by 31.
- dividing by 365.242199 assumes that you want the number of solar years between 00:00 on the first date and 00:00 on the second date, to 9 significant figures.
- the third method assumes you want to calculate how many calendar days between the two dates, relative to the number of calendar days in the specific year that started on the first date (so the same number of calendar days will give you a different number of years, depending on whether there's a leap day between date1 and the same date on the following year).
- the extract(year) approach assumes you want know the difference in whole numbers between the calendar year of the first date and the calendar year of the second date

It's not possible to answer the question perfectly, without knowing which kind of year we are talking about. Do we mean a solar year, or a calendar year, and if we mean a calendar year, do we we want to calculate by months (as if all months were the same length, which they aren't) or by the actual number of days between those dates and in that specific year?

Indeed, if we're talking about calendar years, it's not possible to calculate a fractional number of years in a consistent way at all, since the concept "calendar year" doesn't correspond to a fixed number of days.

The good news is that (aside from the fourth method) all the approaches give the same answer to the first 2 significant figures, as DCookie said. So you can save worrying about what you mean when you say "year", and instead start to think of other concerns such as performance, portability, readability... which also are quite different between these approaches.

I do think though, that whenever a non-programmer asks for something like "the fractional number of years between two dates," they should be punished by being given a detailed explanation of the different ways to calculate it, and why and how they are different, until they agree that it would be better expressed in number of weeks (which at least have the benefit of containing a fixed number of days).